# DB Structure - A user belonging to multiple teams

Tags: mysql, database

If I have a users table with email and login details etc, If a user only belongs to one team I can create a new column called `team` but if that user is on multiple teams how would you structure it?

The best way I can come up with is having a table for that specific user called `PlayersTeams` but at scale that seem like a large number of tables to be creating. Here is the best way I can come up with, but I thought that the more experienced here might have a better suggestion for me.

**Only one team:**

```
PlayerID   email           TeamID
1          John@abc.xyz    123
2          sarah@pqr.stu   456
3          peter@asd.jkl   789
```

**Multiple Teams:**

```
PlayerID    TeamID
1           123
1           456
1           789
2           123
2           789
3           456
3           789
```

I doubt it, but should I have a specific users database and then once a user is logged in, then switch to the team database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many-to-Many relationship is what you are looking for.

Using a third (junction) table would be the correct way to accomplish this scenario. Example table structure:

```
player: player_id, email
team: team_id, name
player_teams: player_id, team_id
```

Comment: And then you can query 1) the `team_id` for the list of `player_id`'s and 2) the `player_id` for all their `team_id`'s. Thanks, I actually hadn't seen the requirement to query from both sides as clearly as that until reading your post.

Comment: Also, you can add arbitrary columns to the junction table like role in the team etc.

Comment: Cool, that's the intention just kept the example simple here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the relationship between team and player is a many to many relationship (a team is comprised of zero, one or more players  &  one player can belong to zero, one or more teams).

The only way to resolve a many to many relationship is through an association table (like the PlayerTeam table your instincts are leading you to).

The benefit of the association table is that you can add addition columns such as position, jersey number, etc...

The association table would be comprised of primary keys of both tables with foreign keys back to the original table...

```
PlayerTeam
----------------------
PlayerID    same datatype and foreign key references to player(player_id)
TeamID      same datatype and foriend key references to team(TeamID)
team_number -- possible additional column for this association
position    -- possible additional column for this association
```

It would be recommended to create the primary key (PlayerID, TeamID)

Comment: Cool, thanks, I didn't know about association tables, I need to have a look at these.